# AWS S3: Reading exif data from image in s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to read only the exif metadata from an image in s3?
Or can we read exif metadata by getting the image in bytes instead of downloading the image as getting bytes is faster?

Currently, downloading and reading exif data using exif extractor seems to be the only way.

Answer (score -2):

Updating the answer based on @Michael's comment.

> Object metadata doesn't include EXIF. For this to work, you would have
>   to extract the EXIF data and add it to the object metadata when the
>   object is uploaded.

Comment: Is there an equivalent Java sdk request for the same? Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer with Java ObjectMetada class information.

Comment: I used clone and looked through the metadata but could not find exif information in it

Comment: @binshi you are correct -- object metadata doesn't include EXIF.  For this to work, you would have to extract the EXIF data and add it to the object metadata when the object is uploaded.